# LibreOffice exe file to convert word to pdf in windows

Tags: windows, command-line, libreoffice

In Ubuntu terminal libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf test.docx I convert document file to pdf file is work fine.

*My doubt is in windows system without install libreoffice to need to convert docuemnt to pdf (i.e) without install libreoffice software only **libreoffice exe** or bat file convert word to pdf is possible?
*Or In java code to execute command prompt to using microsoft office to convert word to pdf is possible?

Comment: You could run libreoffice as a server then send the docs to the server 
libreoffice5.1 -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" OR you could have a shared folder and use libreoffice5.1 --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir "C:\tmp" "C:\tmp\file.doc"

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Libreoffice portable](http://www.downloads.techradar.com/downloads/libreoffice-portable) with the cli :

```
LibreOfficePortable.exe -headless -convert-to pdf untitled.odt
```

I haven't tested it, please let me know if it works on your machine.