# Accessibility Issue

Tags: c#, pdf, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have a word document that is accessibility complaint , and converting it into a pdf pro programmatically using third party tool Xceed ([xceed.com](https://xceed.com)), but after converting a document into pdf, i used to check it's accessibility with Adboe Reader DC Accessibility tool and it is giving lot of issues. Do we have any tool that convert word to pdf programmatically(C#) that have accessibility compliant or any solution of this problem.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566186/print-pdf-in-c-sharp

Comment: @wicky I doubt that any of the approaches listed in that other question generate **tagged** PDF. You need a process that preserves the accessibility features from the source document. The most reliable approach is using the Adobe Acrobat plugin for MS Word. Alternatively, you can directly export tagged PDF from MS Word (2010 or higher).

Comment: Check whether you can use LibreOffice in headless mode (as suggested in [LibreOffice exe file to convert word to pdf in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36335881/6002174)) while passing on a parameter that tells it to generated tagged PDF. Downside: when you import DOCX into Writer, some accessibility features are lost in the process.

Comment: There's a company called SyncFusion that makes commerical libraries that do exactly what you're describing. They aren't cheap, but neither is manually remediating PDFs. https://blog.syncfusion.com/post/converting-word-docs-to-pdfs.aspx I haven't used this product myself, so I can't vouch for the quality of the output, but automated software will only be able to do so much. Any software will likely have issues with things like complex tables, nested lists, text boxes, or poorly formatted source docs.

Comment: Yes - @ChristopheStrobbe , we would like to preserve accessibility feature. we are uploading a docx document , do some manipulation and then convert that edited docx to pdf stream. We are doing everything in .Net Applicatino using C# , so cannot use any .exe to convert pdf.